# change Comments per page

Tags: 8, comments

I need to change the comments per page value, I set it 50 from the field setting but in some pages, I need showing only 10 comments, not 50.
I tried to use this method

```
setSettings([
    'per_page' => '10',
  ]);
```

it chnaged vlaue but sitll page showing 50 resultes.
Code.

```
function my_module_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  $def = $paragraph->getFieldDefinitions();
  $def['field_name']->setSettings(['per_page' => '5',]);
}
```

Comment: Where did you use `setSettings([
    'per_page' => '10',
  ]);` can you post your code ?

Comment: ' function my_module_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  $def = $paragraph->getFieldDefinitions();
  $def['field_name']->setSettings([
    'per_page' => '5',
  ]); '